# What can I do with the Fampyr?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

So, I was recently in Raedric's Hold, fighting the master of that place once more. After defeating him, apparently proving that I'm a better Berath champion than he was a Fampyr proposed to give it's services to me. I agreed.

But now what? The only effect I can see is lowered Glided Vale reputation. I can not find it anywhere in my stronghold, it's not on the hireling list (like the Ogre I once recruited is). What happened? Is it a net-loss situation?

[edit 07.07.2016] On my new playthrough said Fampyr did not offer its services. Perhaps it was removed in some patch? If someone could confirm / find the relevant patch notes this question can probably be closed.

Answer (score 1):

The rep loss is unrelated to the poor Fampyr. It's triggered by a nasty bug, described [here](https://forums.obsidian.net/topic/75692-return-to-raedric-keep-bug/). Sadly, I have no clue what to do with the Fampyr... He disappeared in my case and I wasn't able to talk to him after the fight.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik you also need the quest 'Servant of Death' to be compleated (the order of quest does not matter - you can go back and speak to fampyr after both quests are compleated)

Answer (score 0):

The Fampyr servant becomes available as a hireling after you agree to take them on. You will need to have a hireling slot free in order to hire them (so you might need to dismiss someone if you are already full up). They give +5 defense but -3 prestige, and cost 20 cp per day.